# C : function, returns string as char array

Tags: c

I try to create a function, which returns astring (char array);

I tried different ways,  but I always got error like:

> [Error] conflicting types for 'readCommand'

Code:

```
char* cmd; //char cmd[256]
*cmd = readCommand();

//function
char* readCommand()
{
    char cmd[256];
    fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin);
    return cmd;
}
```

How can I return a string from this function?

Comment: If `cmd` is not declared with the `static` qualifier, trying to access the returned value from `readCommand` will be undefined behavior

Comment: @GovindParmar i tried 'static char cmd[256];' bu the result the same. What I did wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @LeonidZolotarov The error comes from `*cmd = readCommand();` instead of `cmd = readCommand();`, but you're doing it wrong anyway, read the duplicates.